# How to consume a poetry package from a git repository in another poetry-based project

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have two python projects living on github. In the pyproject.toml of the second project I have the first dependency

```
my-module = {git = "ssh://git@github.com/my-org/my-module.git", rev = "master"}
```

however when I run

```
poetry export -f requirements.txt | /venv/bin/pip install -r /dev/stdin
```

This fails with

`ERROR: The editable requirement my-module from git+https://github.com/my-org/my-module@5a357a8aac555cad31373e8d0430f075a45c2305#egg=my-module (from -r /dev/stdin (line 180)) cannot be installed when requiring hashes, because there is no single file to hash`

Do I need to push my-module on github in a different way, or consume them in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

By default poetry will generate a requirements.txt file with hashes and with a `-e` prepended to make the package editable. According to the error message, you might try generating the requirements.txt file without hashes

```
poetry export --without-hashes -f requirements.txt
```

and/or removing the leading `-e` to not have your package installed in editable mode.

```
cp requirements.txt requirements.txt.copy
sed -e "s:^-e ::" < requirements.txt.copy > requirements.txt
```